# Como colocar duas imagens no itext.PdfTemplate

Tags: .net, vb.net, itextsharp

Gostaria de saber se alguém consegui me ajudar preciso fazer a criação de um relatório pdf q no cabeçalho teria duas imagens uma a direita outra a esquerda e o titulo no centro..

Comment: Uma tabela com 3 colunas, talvez.

Comment: O que você já tem?

Comment: Gente obrigado pelo apoio mas o pessoal aqui mudou o projeto e acabamos resolvendo de outra forma..